# Boot entry still there after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu

I had Ubuntu and Windows 7 installed but after removing Ubuntu, the boot list entry still shows up. How do I get rid of it? It hasn't gone after formatting my pc several times with Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 7, go to <kbd>Start</kbd> > <kbd>Run...</kbd> and type **msconfig** and hit enter.

There will be a boot tab and entries for the boot list. Delete the Ubuntu entry, save, and reboot. Make sure you do not delete it if you are not totally sure. You can post the screenshot of the page here if you are not sure.